# AFL: Compare current close with previous high

Tags: pine-script, amibroker

I'm new to AFL. I want to check if the current candle close is greater than the previous high but I'm experiencing the following error. Can you help me in fixing this:

```
if ((lowma > minHighPrice) AND (Close[0] > High[-1]))
```

*Error 10: Subscript out of range. You must not access array elements outside 0..(BarCount-1) range.You are attempted to access non-existing -1st element of array.
Error 6: Condition in IF, WHILE, FOR statements has to be Numeric or Boolean type. YOu can not use array here. Please use [] to access array elements*

```
if (lowma > minHighPrice) AND (Ref(Close, 0) > Ref(High,-1))
```

*Error 6: Condition in IF, WHILE, FOR statements has to be Numeric or Boolean type. YOu can not use array here. Please use [] to access array elements*

Thanks and regards,
Hameed

Comment: An If statement you usually use inside a loop and will need to reference elements in an array using the indexer `myVar[index];` You can also use the `IIF(condition, truepart, falsepart)` to operate on entire arrays. `IIF((lowma > minHighPrice) AND (Close> Ref(High, 01), truepart, falsepart)` [AFL](https://www.amibroker.com/guide/h_understandafl.html)

Answer (score 0):

Orginial Code: `(Close[0] > High[-1])`

My Suggestion: `Close > Ref(Close,-1)`

Try to use `Ref` function